# Dynamically change row number in excel

Tags: excel

I got a file in excel that often changes the row number (My first column) whenever there is a insertion of data. However, there is multiple rows of data with the same row number.

Example: 
1 
1
2
3
3
3

Is there a way I can change them dynamically beside grouping the number together via Filter and change it manually?

Edited.

1

1

1

2

3

4

4

4

Better example. Sorry about the indentation.

Comment: Row Number in first Column?  There are rows, and there are columns, and neither of them change value.  I'm probably misunderstanding -- could you post an example of the data and how/when it goes wrong?  How is this data being inserted, and where?

Comment: I assume, you have "records" of information distributed over 1 or many rows in your file. Value in the first column (let's call it 'id') determines how many rows together make up a single record of info. And you have user scenarios to insert a new "record" somewhere in the middle. I assume that this insertion is manual? if so, you should have rules for inserting records: a) 1 row will be inserted at a time, b) the row of data will be populated and an id assigned before inserting another row of the same record, etc? Please elaborate

Comment: Do you insert to the beginning of the file? Do you need your row number to stay the same for a given set of data.

Comment: Please refer to the example above. I just need to dynamically update them + 1 or -1 when a new block of cells are added.

Comment: Well at this point, you might as well just use `=row()` (or `=row()-1` if you have headers on the first row) to have dynamic record IDs.

Comment: @Jerry I think OP has same value over few rows, so `row()` can't be used.

Comment: Yes I have two rows that has the same 'Row No'. Whenever I insert a row of data with a new 'Row No', I want the rows after the inserted data to auto increment by 1 even if there is duplicate. For Example 1 1 2 2 3 3, if i insert in between 1 and 2. it would be 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 in the 'Row No' Column.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a partial solution.
Set the value only in the first identical value and change only those unique values when a group of rows is inserted:
1       1
1   =A1
1   =A2
2   2
3   3
4   4
4   =A6
4   =A7
Otherwise, you do it from VBA to change all values when a new row is inserted.